# Update 3rd level Nested Table to append a record

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Following the examples found here at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/dml-syntax, we came up with a way that we can update the 3rd level of the table (specifications.dimensions) as such:

```
UPDATE sd97dwo.DetailedInventory
SET specifications.dimensions = 
    STRUCT<depth FLOAT64, height FLOAT64, width FLOAT64>(1, 2, 3)
WHERE 
    product like '%washer%'
    AND EXISTS(select 1 from unnest(comments) as c where c.comment like '%comment%')
```

What we are trying to do now, is update the table to APPEND a record to that same dimensions struct.  However, the various ways we are trying are not successful.  Wanted to see if anyone had any ideas.  The closest we got was the below, but of course returns all the records (as multiple results) for specifications.dimensions so we get the error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

```
UPDATE sd97dwo.DetailedInventory
SET specifications.dimensions
    = (SELECT specifications.dimensions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT<depth FLOAT64, height FLOAT64, width FLOAT64>(4.0,5.0,6.0))
WHERE 
    product like '%washer%'
    AND EXISTS(select 1 from unnest(comments) as c where c.comment like '%comment%')
```

Comment: Other but might be related, how did you overcome the hard limit of **48** maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table? Or try to deal with it? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language

Comment: Our general thinking is that by the time we actually get to that level of updates Google will be willing to up the quotas as with most other things.  However, as long as the behind the scenes work is building an entire new table with the updated fields we will shy away from heavy usage due to cost / time.  I'm just trying to prove benefits / drawbacks and understand the syntax.  Also, do note it's update operations, not fields updated, so if you can get away with updating most of your records in a single pass (using joins or w/e) you may not need all that many on a per table basis.

Comment: I am concerned that still doesn't fit as the query limit is 256K, which is kinda small if you want to put the values in the statements. Also if you put the changed values into a table, and issue the update with a join from that table is kinda tricky and limits the usage. Just concerns I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What we are trying to do now, is update the table to APPEND a record to that same dimensions struct.

What is your schema?
If you are using same schema as in DML documentation then neither "specifications" nor "dimensions" are repeated fields. So you can't append to it. But you can update them directly like:

```
UPDATE sd97dwo.DetailedInventory
SET specifications.dimensions.depth = 1,
     specifications.dimensions.height = 2,
     specifications.dimensions.width = 3
WHERE 
    product like '%washer%'
    AND EXISTS(select 1 from unnest(comments) as c where c.comment like '%comment%')
```

Comment: why not simply `SET specifications.dimensions = STRUCT<depth FLOAT64, height FLOAT64, width FLOAT64>(1, 2, 3)` as it is in the first part of the question? is there any benefit of calling out each element specifically?!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex.  I am using the structures from the docs as you mentioned, and was really just trying to think of different things I may want to do in the future.

A more specific use case is implementing slow changing dimensions within a sales transaction. We want to include historical details about skus in the transaction.  We would have a schema similar to this: {TRANS_KEY, {[TRANS_LINE, SKU, SLS, {[SKU_CLASS, SKU_DEPT, EFF_DT]}]}}  If an item changes class / dept I want to add a record to the existing TRANS_KEY / TRANS_LINE that shows the old {CLASS/DEPT/DT} and the new.

Comment: Ran out of characters, so let me know if you need more clarity.  In order to run the update I would join to a SKU table that contains the new details for skus.

Comment: After having the schema pointed out, I'm able to append to my third nested structure after changing them to repeated fields. This does what I intended:

    UPDATE temp.DetailedInventory
    SET specifications = 
        ARRAY(
           SELECT AS STRUCT s.color, s.warranty, ARRAY_CONCAT(s.dimensions, ARRAY<STRUCT<depth FLOAT64, height FLOAT64, width FLOAT64>>[(9.0, 9.0, 9.0), (5.0, 5.0, 5.0)]) AS dimensions FROM UNNEST(specifications) AS s
        )
WHERE product like '%washer%'